# Example of a relation that is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric but not transitive.

Tags: relations

Please, can you help a beginner mathematician with the following problem?
Is there a binary relation that is **reflexive**, **symmetric**, **antisymmetric** but **not transitive**?

## Definitions:

## Relation

Let be two sets $A$,$B$ $\neq$$\emptyset$. A relation $\mathscr{R}$ of $A$ to $B$ is the ordered triple ($A$,$B$,$\mathscr{R}$)  where $\mathscr{R}$ $\subset$ $A$$\times$$B$, $A$ is called input set, $B$ is called output set and $\mathscr{R}$ is called matching rule or graphic.
**Note**: A particular case of relation is when the input set and output set are equal i.e. $A$=$B$.
 Let $A$ $\neq$$\emptyset$. Hereinafter, we say that $\mathscr{R}$ it is a relation of $A$ to $A$. Furthermore, $(a,b)$$\in$ $\mathscr{R}$, then we will denote $a$ $\mathscr{R}$ $b$.

#### Reflexive

A relation $\mathscr{R}$  is called reflexive iff: $\forall x\in A:$ $x$ $\mathscr{R}$ $x$.

#### Symmetric

A relation $\mathscr{R}$  is called symmetric iff: $\forall x,y\in A:$ $x$ $\mathscr{R}$ $y$ $\Rightarrow$ $y$ $\mathscr{R}$ $x$.

#### Transitive

A relation $\mathscr{R}$  is called transitive iff: $\forall x,y,z\in A:$ $x$ $\mathscr{R}$ $y$ $\wedge$ $y$ $\mathscr{R}$ $z$ $\Rightarrow$ $x$ $\mathscr{R}$ $z$.

#### Antisymmetric

A relation $\mathscr{R}$  is called antisymmetric iff: $\forall x,y\in A:$ $x$ $\mathscr{R}$ $y$ $\wedge$ $y$ $\mathscr{R}$ $x$ $\Rightarrow$ $x$ $=$ $y$
If the answer is true, then please show me a couple of examples.
Thank you.
Quote of the day:
"There is no branch of mathematics, however abstract, which may not some day be applied to phenomena of the real world".
Nicolai Ivanovitch Lobachevsky
1792-1856

Comment: As I told you, it can be only isolated points.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Please, could you explain with a couple of examples?

Comment: The answer of Alephnull shows that a relation with your characteristics is nessesary identity, which is transitive. So you can't ask for non transivity

Comment: Pretty sure Nicolai Lobachevsky is wrong...

Comment: See also: [Examples and Counterexamples of Relations which Satisfy Certain Properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3802279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have such a relation. It is symmetric so xRy implies yRx. It is antisymmetric so xRy and yRx implies x=y. But putting this together we get xRy implies x=y. Thus our relation is the identity function over some set. But the identity function is transitive vacuously. This is a contradiction.

Comment: i'll study your proof. Thank so much..

Comment: Thank you. I've already understood.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is correct, but it seems that if the relation is symmetric then x R y -> y R x. Hence, x R y ^ y R x -> x = y. So, if you have x R y, y R z, since x = y -> x R z, so the relation is necessarily transitive.

Comment: When you don't know if your answer is correct, it's best to leave your "answer" as a *comment* below Oromion's post.

Comment: oh ok gotcha. thanks.

Comment: i'll study your proof too. Thank you.